# Codeigniter cart: process the class in client side

Tags: codeigniter, client-side, shopping-cart

I suspect that data which processed with shopping class Codeigniter is locates in our browser, so we can see and edit our cart with client side script such as javascript.
Am i true? if i am wrong, please explain me how its work

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. CodeIgniter is a PHP framework
2. PHP only runs server-side. It CAN NEVER run on the client-side browser.

Putting 1 and 2 together: Your shopping cart does not exist client-side and cannot be modified client-side.

However, you can make an AJAX request from the client to the server, and then modify the shopping cart server-side, and send back the results.

Comment: about "php CAN NEVER run" I'd not be so opinionated. http://phpjs.hertzen.com/  but sure about the question you're absolutely right.

Comment: It seems like it cross-compiles the PHP to JS. It would be similar to claiming a browser can run CoffeeScript, when really it first needs to be cross-compiled to JS.

Comment: Read the link, I'm not actually sure whether it cross-compiles or not. If it does not, I stand corrected. Either way, that's an interesting link.

Comment: Please you read the link. "The code can be directly run in your browser, meaning you can execute php code straight out of your browser!". Also try to run any php code looking to developers console - net panel to ensure that no requests sending code you write.

Comment: No, I get that the PHP is not sent to the server and eval'ed there. What I meant was did the guy write a PHP VM in JS, or does he cross compile the PHP to JS, and then essentially just execute JS.